If $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = I$, then $m\left\{x: f(x) > \frac{I}{2}\right\} \geq \frac{I}{2}$
Consider a measurable function $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ such that $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = I$. Prove that
$$m\left\{x: f(x) > \frac{I}{2}\right\} \geq \frac{I}{2} \tag{$\star$}$$
I'm not sure how to go about this. Plus, I think there is a typo. I think the $\frac{I}{2}$ on the RHS of the $\geq$ should be $\frac{1}{2}$ $-$ because our domain is $[0,1]$;  hence, the measure of the set in $(\star)$ is bounded above by $1$, yet no restriction is imposed on $I$ (yet certainly, there are functions over $[0,1]$ that have large integral values). I will thus be attempting to show
$$m\left\{x: f(x) > \frac{I}{2}\right\} \geq \frac{1}{2} \tag{$\star \star$}$$
(unless I am misunderstanding something fundamental here) Moving forward with this correction, I claim I have come up with a counterexample: Consider for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
n & 0 \leq  x < \frac{1}{n} \\
0 & \frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq 1 
\end{cases}$$
Then certainly $f$ is measurable, has domain $[0,1]$ and $\int_0^1 f(x) = 1 =:I^*$. But we notice that
$$m\left\{x: f(x) \geq \frac{I^*}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\right\}  = \frac{1}{n} = \frac{I^*}{n}$$
which serves as a counterexample to the above problem if $n \geq 3$.

Note that my example serves to counter both interpretations $(\star)$ and $(\star)$. At this point, I desire to know whether the my correction in $(\star\star)$ is justified and if my counterexample does not hold, then how might I better approach this problem?

I don't see anything wrong with your counterexample. Where did you get the statement of the question? Do you have some reason to believe it's a credible source?

Your counterexample is invalid because when $n \geq 3$, the range of $f$ is outside of $[0, 1]$!

oh I completely missed the fact that the codomain is supposed to be $[0,1]$ too.

@AnCar You still made a very good point of asking the OP to state the source of the problem.

Due to the codomain restriction, one can proceed by contradiction. Let the level set (hence measurable since $f$ is too) given by $f(x)>I/2$ be $X$. Then the integral is bounded above by $m(X)+(1-m(X))I/2=I/2+m(X)(1-I/2)$. If $m(X)<I/2$, this means that the integral is bounded strictly above by $I-I^2/4$, contradiction.

Just decompose the integral into two parts:
\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^1 f(x)dx = \int_{\{x: f(x) > I/2\}}f(x)dx + \int_{\{x: f(x) \leq I/2\}}f(x)dx \\
& \leq m(\{x: f(x) > I/2\}) + \frac{I}{2}. 
\end{align*}
In the inequality above, we used the condition that both the domain (to bound the second part) and the codomain (to bound the first part) of $f$ are $[0, 1]$. Rearranging terms then yields
\begin{align*}
m(\{x: f(x) > I/2\}) \geq I - \frac{I}{2} = \frac{I}{2}.
\end{align*}

Thanks for the post. Is this to say that the comments above stating that the problem is false are invalid?

@GrigorHakobyan Yes, have you checked my comment under your question to invalidate your "counterexample"?

I was mistaken when I said this is wrong because I hadn't noticed the fact that the range of the function is also included in $[0,1]$. Corrected this in the comments, but @Zhanxiong's answer is a bit crisper than what I wrote.

Oh I see now; I guess I can't read. Thank you. To ensure I understand: regarding the bound of the second part, if the second part had measure exceeding $\frac{I}{2}$, then $I$ would exceed $I$, a contradiction. That makes sense. But why does it matter that the domain and codomain are the same? It seems that all we used is the fact that $\int_0^1 f(x) , dx= I$ in order to split up $\int_0^1 f(x) , dx$ in a clever way.

@GrigorHakobyan No need to use proof by contradiction to bound the second part, it is as simple as $$\int_{x: f(x) \leq I/2}f(x)dx \leq \int_{x: f(x) \leq I/2}\frac{I}{2}dx = \frac{I}{2}m({x: f(x) \leq I/2}) \leq \frac{I}{2}m([0, 1]) = \frac{I}{2}.$$
